# How to display parent form when input text is on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish there was a CSS selector that could do this, because I'm a complete noob when it comes to javascript.

The HTML is basically this:

```
<div class="searchmenu">
 <form id="search">
  <fieldset>
   <input type="text" class="inputbox search"/>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

The CSS is this:

```
.searchmenu form {
 display:none;
}

searchmenu:hover form {
    display:block;
}
```

The form is already displayed when the div is hovered, now I also want it to keep it displayed while the input text is on focus.

I tried searching for other cases, but they either don't work for my case or I don't know how to implement them D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/znj2nL4c/)**

You can use jQuery focus & blur event.

**Like this:**

```
$('.inputbox').focus(function(){
    $('.searchmenu').addClass('is_focused');
});
$('.inputbox').blur(function(){
    $('.searchmenu').removeClass('is_focused');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.searchmenu form {
 display:none;
}
.searchmenu:hover form,
.searchmenu.is_focused form{
    display:block;
}
.searchmenu{
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yours is clearly working in the demo.But, how do I implement the script? As I said, I'm a complete noob when it comes to this :P

Comment: well you add javascript in 'script' tag & you can add jQuery library by adding following code: <script src="https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

I would recommend you to visit [codeschool.com](https://www.codeschool.com/) & take HTML/JS classes.

Answer (score 0):

bind the input field to jquery event
For example

```
$(".inputbox .search").bind("focus keyup",function(){
$(".searchmenu").css("display","block");
});
```

I hope this would be helpful to you